# Can't log out wordpress user after changing my login.php file

Tags: php, wordpress

So I've changed my login.php file in order to change the URL of login page.
What I did was to go to login.php file and change this line

```
$message .= network_site_url( "wp-login.php?action=rp&key=$key&login="
```

to

```
$message .= network_site_url( "new-login-url.php?action=rp&key=$key&login="
```

and the changed login.php name to new-login-url.php.

Everything works ok accept I can't log out from my user on website..
What can I do to fix that?

Thank you :]

Comment: `<a href="<?= esc_url( wp_logout_url( get_permalink() ) ); ?>">Logout</a>` have you tried to logout via the logout url ?

Comment: @amarinediary Thank you for your time.
Can you give me a little direction on where to set this line?
I have been searching for it within the login.php file..

Comment: paste that in your index and click it.

Answer (score 0):

Need to change **all** *wp-login.php* **to** *new-login-url.php*

You can simply replace text in multiple files.

I defined **CONSTANT** in **wp-config.php**

```
//Define new login file path

define ('WP_LOGIN_FILE', 'new-login-url.php');
```

> This is useful when you want to **change file name** for some reason.
> Need to change only one file.

Now replace all wp-login.php from :-

```
new-login-url.php
wp-includes\general-template.php
```

as

```
'wp-login.php?  =>  WP_LOGIN_FILE.'?  # remove wp-login.php and append WP_LOGIN_FILE to string 

'wp-login.php'  =>  WP_LOGIN_FILE
```

**NOTE:-**
This solution worked for me for simple login/logout from dashboard.

There are number of occurrences of wp-login.php in many file related to functions,themes,plugins etc ... which is not considered while writing this answer.